# Wrong year assigned to a ticklabel in plotly.js

Tags: plotly.js

The following image contains a part of a scatter plot generated with plotly.js:

[image: First ticklabel is wrong]

The red arrow shows the wrong value in ticklabel. It should be 53 2020.

If a zoom is made, then the right ticklabels are obtained:

[image: Right ticklabels]

The layout for xaxis.tickformat gives Week / Year.

This problem appears just when the ticklabel is generated when date is December 31st of any year.

The layout for xaxis is set as:

```
 xaxis: {
            type: 'date',                
            tickformat: '%V\n%Y',
            ticks: 'outside',
            ticklabelmode: 'period',
            tickmode: 'auto',              
            autorange: true,                            
        },
```

After a little research, the issue seems to be related to:

- Plotly uses Date.getUTCFullyear to calculate ticklabels,
- For a date given on December 31st, the result may be different according to [getUTCFullYear in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear).

One attention calling point is that the value of data showed in the first image when the mouse is over the point (following the green arrow), is the right one: 53, 2020!

The code for this issue can be found at:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/pedrogarcia1965/pen/ZEjMmWQ)

Please, can anyone help to solve this issue? Thanks.